# How do I add taxonomy terms and vocabularies to an exportable deployment plan?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, features, deployment

I'm in the process of developing an installation profile for a new site. We're using Features to export much of our functionality, and are very interested in using the Deploy module integration with UUID to handle the thorny issues stemming from exported content not having the same unique IDs on multiple deployments. Being able to export entities into a deployment plan and import them with Features would be an absolute godsend, and this is working with basic node content from what I've seen so far (I'm familiar with the concept of creating a fetch-only deployment plan and exporting it later).

However, I have a content type that references multiple taxonomies, each with a closed, pre-defined vocabulary. These vocabularies (and their terms) need to be exported, so that they can be referenced by the appropriate fields (for instance, a list of terms representing venues should be selectable from a drop-down). I haven't yet found a way to add these to a deployment plan, despite hearing on the [soon-to-be-deprecated UUID Features](http://drupal.org/node/1245582) issue queue that this should be possible. Is there something I've overlooked, or is there a better approach?

Comment: Where did you hear that UUID Features is "soon-to-be-deprecated"?

Comment: Linked the relevant issue in my question. Deploy does seem like it will be a much more robust alternative, though at the moment it is rough around the edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have stumbled my way through to a solution. Vocabularies don't need to be exported via UUID, as they already have their own machine name, but any terms within those vocabularies still need to be added to a deployment plan so they can be exported (inadvertently adding a vocabulary to the plan throws errors).

Using the latest development snapshots (as of March 14, 2012) of UUID, Deploy, Entity Dependency API, Views and Rules, it is possible to stitch together a UI for adding taxonomy terms to a plan. First, a managed fetch-only deployment plan must be created.

Next, a Rules component must be created using Rules, with a taxonomy term as a single parameter and a single action that adds the entity to the selected deployment plan. Note, however, that the current development snapshot of Deploy does not allow you to use Rules to add to a fetch-only managed deployment plan (I had to write [a trivial patch that allows this behavior](http://drupal.org/node/1483896#comment-5736770)).

Next, one should create a view of all taxonomy terms, adding a Bulk Operations checkbox using Views Bulk Operations. If you have created your Rules component as above, VBO will allow you to select your component as a task to perform on all checked entities.

Now that your form is configured, all that's left to do is visit the view and add the necessary taxonomy terms, and select the relevant components to export via Features. Gotcha: There is no dependency checking in Features after adding the taxonomy terms via uuid_entities. You have to remember adding the vocabulary yourself, or tragedy and error messages will ensue.

Answer (score -2):

For Drupal 7 :

There are a few ways to do this

- If you are importing the terms from another Drupal site use Node
  export module - drupal.org/project/node_import
- If you are planning to export or import from a csv file :
  drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv
- If you just want to cut and paste the list (one per line) and add to
  a vocabulary : drupal.org/project/batch_add_terms